# The new Strapi (3.0.2) application can't be started in server

Tags: node.js, strapi

I have created a project in my local and run smoothly here but in server it gets stuck at `Opening the admin panel...`.

I don't understand where the wrong/error is occurring.

[image]

Comment: What happens when you try to go to http://localhost:7777/admin ?

Comment: This is server, so 'localhost' shouldn't not work. @ghosh

Comment: @MdShamimHossain did you manage to solve this?